# running C++ code on VS code on Ubuntu and get this error collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm newbie to VS code and I'm trying to run basic C++ code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error :  undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: How is your project set up?

Comment: Code's good. Has to be a mistake in the configuration. Easy thing to do with VSC, unfortunately.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I have just downloaded it and added C/C++ Microsoft extension and Code Runner extension, and that's it.

Comment: @user4581301 I can't reach to the mistake in the configuration

Answer (score 1):

I added This Task configuration and it works fine :

`

```
{"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": ["g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","a.exe"]
    },
    {
        "label": "Compile and run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": [
            "g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out", "&&", "clear" , "&&" , "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true  
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    },
    
]}
```

`